# How will a car with two locked wheels go down from an inclined plane?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration, friction

I asked a question earlier about a car going down an inclined plane. The front wheels are locked and the rear wheels are free to move. The car goes down while the front wheels slip.

I thought that the slipping wheels experience less friction than the freely rotating rear wheels. So the free wheels would go down behind the locked wheels in front. Which means that the car moves down with the front facing down.

But I'm not sure anymore. A car with free wheels takes a longer distance before it has stopped than a car with locked wheels. Which would imply lesser stopping force for free wheels.

But does this apply for the situation I sketched? In this case the car is under the influence of a force making it go faster and we know a car with smoking tires accelerates spectacularly but accelerating just beneath the point that the tires slip will do better (though I can't imagine formula I drivers to do this).

What will happen?

Edit
This question is not a copy of the existing question. I *question* that question. I initially thought it goes down with locked wheels first. But I'm not sure now. I didn't ask this in that question but assumed it.

Answer (score 1):

A locked wheel, that is sliding along the ground experiences [*sliding friction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Kinetic_friction)—a force that is proportional to the weight on the wheel and proportional to the speed of the sliding motion.

A rolling wheel experiences [*static friction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Static_friction), and that force is proportional to the torque on the wheel. If the car is in neutral, and nobody is pressing the brake pedal, then the torque will be zero, and the frictional force on the rolling wheel will be zero. On the other hand, if somebody is pressing the brake as the car rolls down the hill, then the magnitude of the frictional force will depend on how hard the brake is pressed. It could be either greater or less than the sliding frictional force that the locked wheels feel.

---

P.S., Re, "smoking wheels." I don't know much about high-performance driving, but I do know that drag racers try to get their tires smoking hot just *before* the start of a race because the [*coefficient of friction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction) between hot rubber and the pavement is greater than it would be between cold rubber and pavement. But, I don't know whether they want the tires to slip at all or by how much once the green light flashes.

Comment: So if a car rolls down and suddenly you block the front wheels, it depends?